# How to load modules in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to load the `request` module in my project's functions folder for cloud functions. However, when I try to do so, I get an error:

```
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'request'
```

I used npm to install it, and did so in both my project's root folder and the functions folder. Please help.

EDIT: It is missing from my package.json file, but the folder "request" does exist in my node_modules folder.

package.json inside functions folder:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.7.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Did you install it by typing `npm i request` or did you do it in another way? Is there a `node_modules` folder in your projects root? If yes, is there a `request` folder?

Comment: Yes, there is a request folder in my node_modules folder at both the root of my project and within the functions folder. I used npm to install it.

Comment: Are you sure this is a `request` related issue? Do other packages work normally? (If you're not sure you can test it with a demo package like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/example-package) which just prints demo text).

Comment: The functions deploy perfectly when I comment out the ´const request = require("request")´ line. So, I am guessing that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the contents of your package.json.

Comment: Edited my question, the package is missing from the package.json file but like I said in my question, the folder "request" is inside my node_modules folder--it contains several files including index.js and request.js.

Comment: Just add the module name with the version under "dependencies" same as "firebase-admin": "^5.7.0".